# Docker daemon windows 7 : concurrent downloads

Tags: docker

I've installed the docker toolbox on my machine. Once I try to pull down some images from a repository with docker pull, several of them "timeout". [The docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#concurrent-downloads) recommends that I configure the docker daemon to configure the number of concurrent download sessions:

```
dockerd --max-concurrent-downloads 1
```

However, when I execute the above command, I get the following error:

```
Error starting daemon: This version of Windows does not support the docker daemon
```

If I run docker.exe daemon I get the following error:

```
`docker daemon` is not supported on Windows. Please run `dockerd` directly
```

Is there a different way I can limit the number of concurrent downloads with the docker toolbox?

Comment: looks like this is bug in docker, https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1671

Comment: @techtrainer I think that this person has a full docker env, using windows 10. I am using windows 7, and don't have an option to kick off such a daemon

Comment: are you using Dockerfile or docker-compose yaml files?

Comment: @techtrainer I'm using a Dockerfile

Comment: not sure if this will work for u or not but, parallel to dockerfile create another file called '.env' and put max-concurrent-downloads=1 inside it. then try to build. if this doesnt work then, try 'docker pull max-concurrent-downloads=1' ....

Comment: I'll try the latter recommendation here in a bit. the former one would probably not work too well, given i am doing a "docker pull", no?

Comment: I had faced similar issue and got it fixed using the mechanism of .env and good thing is, you dont have to set this again and again. so, its suitable for CI/CD too.

Comment: @techtrainer i'm afraid that neither recommendation worked. the former ( i placed into the directory where i am executing docker pull from ) and the latter complained I cannot use more than 1 argument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docker toolbox nests the docker daemon (`dockerd`) inside a virtual machine that you can modify using `docker-machine ssh`.

The typical installation of Docker toolbox uses the [Oracle Virtualbox](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/virtualbox/) driver, which uses by default the [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker) image.

According to [the documentation of boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#docker-daemon-options), you can add extra arguments for the docker deamon (ie. dockerd) by modifying the `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` file:

> **Docker daemon options**
>
> If you need to customize the options used to
>   start the Docker daemon, you can do so by adding entries to the
>   `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` file on the persistent partition inside
>   the Boot2Docker virtual machine. Then restart the daemon.

If you are using this configuration (virtualbox + boot2docker), then the following command line might help you. Execute it in your Window shell, it will add the `dockerd` argument `--max-concurrent-downloads` with the value 1 for you, in the machine called "default":

```
docker-machine ssh default "echo \"EXTRA_ARGS=\\\"\$EXTRA_ARGS --max-concurrent-downloads 1\\\"\" | sudo tee -a /var/lib/boot2docker/profile"
```

Do not forget to restart your machine with `docker-machine restart default`.

By doing so I was able to add any [dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) argument (mind the version of dockerd used by boot2docker though).